# What happens with TCP connections on SIGNAL NEWNYM?

Tags: circuit, protocol

When I send the NEWNYM command tor will build new circuits. I'm wondering what happens with open TCP connections. Will tor wait a certain timeout to give them a chance to close, or do I break those connections?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Requesting a NEWNYM over the control port will tell Tor to consider the currently used circuits "dirty" (this normally happens after 10 minutes, with a few exceptions), at this point it will no longer attach new streams (connections) to the "dirty" circuit, and instead will attach them to a "clean" circuit (it doesn't normally build a fresh one at the time, it has some pre-built and waiting for use).

It will not break the existing connections, it only ensures that new connections, that are made after the NEWNYM signal, are attached to a "clean" circuit.

https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt#n415

```
  NEWNYM    -- Switch to clean circuits, so new application requests
               don't share any circuits with old ones.  Also clears
               the client-side DNS cache.  (Tor MAY rate-limit its
               response to this signal.)
```

---

Resources:

[`src/or/main.c:signewnym_impl`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/main.c?id=tor-0.2.8.6#n1212) is called to handle `NEWNYM` signals, which does the following

[`src/or/circuitlist.c:circuit_mark_all_dirty_circs_as_unusable`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/circuitlist.c?id=tor-0.2.8.6#n1661) marks any previously used (dirty) circuits as unusable, so that subsequent connections will not use them

[`src/or/addressmap.c:addressmap_clear_transient`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/addressmap.c?id=tor-0.2.8.6#n293) this clears the client-side DNS cache, as mentioned in the spec (any mapping between address and IP)

[`src/or/rendclient.c:rend_client_purge_state`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/rendclient.c?id=tor-0.2.8.6#n35) clears the state of the rendezvous client (hidden services) to avoid possible links between the old and new nym because of the new nym starting with the end state of the old nym.

It then updates information about when and how often it has performed a `NEWNYM` signal, as the spec mentions it may rate-limit it, which Tor does by default.

The resource to go by *should* be the control-spec definition for the `NEWNYM` signal, the implementation is subject to change.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You break those connections.

Tor will not wait.

To be clear, you would start your own apache and hidden service inside or better "open-net" service, thereafter open something like:

```
<?php echo "One";sleep(100000);echo "Two" ?>
```

And try to play with `NewNym`.

Tor must not send "RST" after each `NewNym`. However, this practice would be much peaceful to the server's sides.

Comment: Could you provide some reference? Sleeping 100000 seconds, I would expect hitting a timeout. I'm more interested in short term connections (within 3s). Reading through similar questions and resources I get the impression that Tor is smart enough not to break existing TCP connections.

Comment: This is incorrect, you do not break existing connections.