# Clearing the client side DNS cache provides privacy improvement?

Tags: deanonymization, dns, protocol, source-code

**Context.** In my quest on figuring out if I must use [`NEWNYM` signal or stream isolation](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/signal-newnym-vs-stream-isolation) is enough for me I dig into the code and narrowed down the possible privacy improvements that `NEWNYM` can bring over simple stream isolation, so I can ask more specific questions. One of it is clearing the client side DNS cache.

**Goal.** My goal is to be able to talk with a server with two different identity, without the server, learning let's say Alice and Bob are the same user. Where the server is a hidden service.

**What I know.** [This answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/what-happens-with-tcp-connections-on-signal-newnym) explains one thing that Tor does for `NEWNYM` request:

> [`src/or/addressmap.c:addressmap_clear_transient`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/addressmap.c?id=tor-0.2.8.6#n293) this clears the client-side DNS cache, as mentioned in the spec (any mapping between address and IP)

Looking into the code `CLEARDNSCACHE` signal does exactly this, [it calls the same `addressmap_clear_transient()`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/main.c?id=tor-0.2.8.6#n2677) method.

**Question.** Is there a risk the server can learn the connection between Alice and Bob without clearing the client side DNS cache? If so, then how much of this risk is?

**For reference I also drop the code here, its comments may be useful:**

```
/** Remove all entries from the addressmap that are set to expire, ever. */
void
addressmap_clear_transient(void)
{
  addressmap_get_mappings(NULL, 2, TIME_MAX, 0);
}
```

[And finally:](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/addressmap.c?id=tor-0.2.8.6#n1076)

```
/** Iterate over all address mappings which have expiry times between
 * min_expires and max_expires, inclusive.  If sl is provided, add an
 * "old-addr new-addr expiry" string to sl for each mapping, omitting
 * the expiry time if want_expiry is false. If sl is NULL, remove the
 * mappings.
 */
void
addressmap_get_mappings(smartlist_t *sl, time_t min_expires,
                        time_t max_expires, int want_expiry)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the client side DNS cache DOES NOT provide privacy improvement against hidden services.
Clearing the client side DNS cache DOES provide privacy improvement against clearnet connections.

## Sources

### Example Of Privacy Loss

Ethan Heilman provided an example of privacy loss in a slack conversation due to DNS chaching:

> Eve tells a host Alice she wishes to fingerprint that dnsname A maps to IP addr 1 and Eve tells Bob that dnsname A maps to IP addr 2.
>   Alice and Bob cache this mapping for say 2 years.
>   Eve can always tell Alice's computer since it will access dnsname A using IP addr 1, where as Bob will us IP addr 2
>   DNS cache is used so that users don't have to constantly query DNS servers

### Hidden Services Not Affected

According to [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/712/15388): there is no DNS involved. [Another useful answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/672/how-do-onion-addresses-exactly-work/674#674) explains exactly how hidden services work. Therefore I conclude clearing the DNS cache does nothing for privacy, if the communication remains within the onion network.